# SQL query - How to exclude WHERE for specific field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

See the SQL query below, it work fine. It calculate the number of Yes, NOT, Other and the number of matching mobile number [Sales field] (`D.MobileNo = S.mobile`)

```
SELECT D.Username, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yes, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'Not' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Not, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Other, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN S.mobile IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Sales, 
      COUNT(*) as TOTAL 
FROM dairy as D 
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT mobile FROM sales) as S on D.MobileNo = S.mobile 
WHERE source = 'Network' 
      AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= 1309474800 
      AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= 1311894000 
GROUP BY D.Username 
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

I want to exclude `WHERE` for the `Sales` field - it should not be part from `CheckDate`. Meaning it should check any record in the `dairy` table without `CheckDate` for the `Sales` field.

How can that be done?

Comment: Write a second query. To elaborate: where is evaluated, so that you can work with a reduced set for the rest of your Select. To "exclude" where for sales means that the rdbms has to reconsider which rows to get out of the table.

Comment: @cularis How would you do that from my example?

Comment: What do you mean? Just copy that query here, delete the fields you don't need and remove the date-stuff in where.

Comment: btw, it would help if you could spell `diary`

Comment: Could you write SQL for my solution, Im not be able to fig it out :(

Comment: @Bohemian: but maybe he **is** managing sales from a dairy farm?

Comment: Does column Username also exist in table SALES?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Are you milking this for all it's worth?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want those results in only one query, this might do the trick.

```
SELECT D.Username, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'Yes' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= 1309474800 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= 1311894000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yes, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'Not' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= 1309474800 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= 1311894000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Not, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = ''    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= 1309474800 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= 1311894000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Other, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN S.mobile IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Sales, 
    COUNT(*) as TOTAL,
    SUM(CASE WHEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= 1309474800 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= 1311894000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTALINCHECKDATE
FROM dairy as D 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT mobile FROM sales) as S on D.MobileNo = S.mobile 
WHERE source = 'Network' 
GROUP BY D.Username 
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

Note that "TOTAL" will count all rows (including those who where not within your CheckDate range), TOTALINCHECKDATE return the same value as in your previous query.

Obviously, this can still be optimized.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it and will let you know. How is second query is possible for my solution?  You can post second solution if you like

Answer (score 0):

Assuming username exists also in SALES table

```
SELECT Username,SUM(Yes) As Yes, SUM(`Not`) As `Not`
  , SUM(Other) As Other, SUM(sales) Sales, SUM(total)
FROM (
-- get diary data
SELECT username,mobileNo As mobile, 
      CASE WHEN D.type = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Yes, 
      CASE WHEN D.type = 'Not' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as `Not`, 
      CASE WHEN D.type = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Other, 
      0 As sales, 1 as total
FROM dairy as D 
WHERE source = 'Network' 
      AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= 1309474800 
      AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= 1311894000 

UNION ALL
-- get all sales
SELECT DISTINCT username,mobile, 0 as Yes, 0 as `Not`, 0 As Other, 1 As sales, 0 As total
FROM sales
  WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= 1309474800 
      AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= 1311894000 
) AS a
GROUP BY Username
```

Also try your original query with date addition

```
SELECT D.Username, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yes, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = 'Not' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Not, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN D.type = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Other, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN S.mobile IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Sales, 
      COUNT(*) as TOTAL 
FROM dairy as D 
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT mobile FROM sales WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= 1309474800 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= 1311894000 ) as S on D.MobileNo = S.mobile 
WHERE source = 'Network' 
      AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) >= 1309474800 
      AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CheckDate) <= 1311894000 
GROUP BY D.Username 
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

Comment: I get an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') As Not, SUM(Other) As Other, SUM(sales) Sales, SUM(total) FROM ( SELECT Userna' at line 1`

Comment: more error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN D.type = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Other, 0 As sales, 1 as total ' at line 7`

Comment: It appear to work fine and its much faster and but the 'sales' result is wrong. It should match mobile number from sales table  against diary mobile number. If you see my first example I used `D.MobileNo = S.mobile` - how to fix this?

Comment: I was a little confused. I updated my code and also provide your initial code fixed with date filter for sales

Comment: WHERE CheckDate should be excluded for the 'sales' field. It should match mobile number from sales but sale.submit_date = today date

Comment: @user791022: What is `sale.submit_date`? There's not a word of it in the original post. Please review your question and add all the necessary details there that are missing.